# Java interface and extending ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, interface

I am trying to understand Java and I found this code in a text book:

```
public EArrayList filt(Func a)
{

}
```

where apply is in an interface called Func
I understood that this method applies a function filter on a list and returns a new list filtered. However I can't understand why `Object elem` is used. I tried the code and it won't work if I rename `Object`.
Also I can't understand the following line:

```
if((Boolean)a.apply(elem) == true)
```

(what does Boolean stand for apart from return type)

Can someone send me a good link to understand better how this works since I searched a lot about interfaces and never came across this format.

Comment: If you kept reading your book, you would probably get your answer. Look up `casting`.

Comment: It is very hard to answer the question without more context - what is the interface of Func? Definition of EArrayList class ?

Comment: Take a look what `get(i)` returns!, and `a.apply` returns an Object

Comment: I reverted your question; it was a *lot* better with the code rather than the "send me a good link" portion, as the latter is not an acceptable question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

> ...However I can't understand why `Object elem` is used.

The likelihood is that `EArrayList` extends `ArrayList`, but doesn't give it a type bound - hence, it can hold any object.

Typically, you find `List`s with some type bound, such as `List<String>`, or `List<Integer>`.  If you omit that, then you are dealing with only `Object`s.

You're also doing it again with `Func a` - it has a type bound of `<S, T>`, which one could presume that you're going from a type of `S` to a type of `T`.  But that is omitted as well, so you're only dealing with `Func<Object, Object>`.

That's where this cast comes from:

```
(Boolean)a.apply(elem)
```

You can omit the `== true` part.  You're checking boolean values.

Java only knows that it is returning an `Object` from `apply`, but you don't want an `Object` - you want a `Boolean`.  Java will attempt to cast it to a `Boolean` for you, [if it can be cast to one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5).  That *could* blow up at runtime, which means that this particular piece of code is a bug waiting to have a `AbstractObjectFactoryImpl` inserted into the list, waiting to try to be cast to a `Boolean`.

This is why you want to use Generics.  [They protect you from runtime failures like that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) by enforcing this stuff at compile time, virtually eliminating type casts.

Had this been done with generics, you would see declarations like this:

```
// Assuming that there is a generic type T on the class:
public EArrayList<T> filter(Func<Boolean, T> a) {
    int size = size();
    EArrayList<T> arr = new EArrayList<T>();

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        T elem = get(i);
        if(a.apply(elem)) {
            arr.add(elem);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: It telling me incompatible types for the i in:  T elem = get(i);

Comment: Probably because I don't know enough about your object; remember, I said there were assumptions made in that you had a generic type `T` on your class, and that whatever you were getting from `get()` was also of type `T`.

Comment: I have this: public class EArrayList<T> extends ArrayList and get(i) where i is of type int in a for loop..

Comment: It should be `EArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>`; that way, your parent class gets the generic type, and not just your base class.

Comment: How can I create an instance from it then? Is  EArrayList al = al.filter(); allowed?